# How can I tell who created a Hyper-V guest after the fact?

Tags: hyper-v

I have a situation where I have Hyper-V Servers being created on a customer's system.

Is there any way I can find out who created them?

I realise anybody could get hold of the Administrator account details, but I have several different accounts that could have created them.

I have seen articles on VMWare: http://www.virtu-al.net/2010/02/23/who-created-that-vm/ but nothing on Hyper-V. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean guests not hv servers? If so then nothing is audited other then maybe a causual relationship between guest install times and hv host server security logs. But thats going to be almost worthless!  Not sure if configuing azman will improve this or not.

Comment: Yes you are quite right I did mean guests. You are saying what I feared and there may be no way to trace the owner/creator.

Answer (score 1):

Logs, look at them.

Comment: If you can. Likely the info has already been retired in the logs - too old.

Comment: How can you say that, we have literally no idea when this happened or the size of their logs.